# subprocess crashes on osx python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython, multiprocessing, fork

I have a GUI software in which I wanted to do some heavy tasks so I create new subprocesses to run those tasks. To do this I am using multiprocessing module and this works perfectly fine on windows as well as unix. However when I try  the same for OSX 10.6 process crash occurs and I get a long error report which I cannot decipher.

Here is something I used to make a sub-process :-

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target = encode.encode , args = (self.path,self.savePath,) , name = "Encode Process")
p.start()
temp = wx.ProgressDialog('Please wait...', 'Encoding the File....This may take several minutes....\n\t....so sit back and relax....',parent = self,style = wx.PD_APP_MODAL | wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
temp.SetSize((450,130))
while len(multiprocessing.active_children()) != 0:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      if not temp.UpdatePulse("Encoding the File....This may take several minutes...\n\tso sit back and relax.....")[0]:
                   p.terminate()
                   terminated = True
                   break
temp.Destroy()
p.join()
p.terminate()
```

Here is the crash report :-

```
Path:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  Python [52639]

Date/Time:       2013-07-23 12:22:46.170 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          14328 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           9
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      DE5488A5-8468-4937-800F-F898E4F09392

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000d28e02e
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ...ple.ApplicationServices.ATS  0x929b43a0 _eGetGlyphVectorIndex + 219
1   ...ple.ApplicationServices.ATS  0x929bec46 OldGlyphsCacheRun(TStrike*, int, unsigned long, unsigned short const*, void (*)(unsigned long, unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned char* const*, void const*), void*) + 354
2   ...ple.ApplicationServices.ATS  0x929c2502 _eGCGetGlyphDeviceMetrics + 475
3   ...ple.ApplicationServices.ATS  0x929c56fd GCGetGlyphDeviceMetrics + 117
4   com.apple.QD                    0x906cc386 GetLayoutDevMetricsGroup(ATSGlyphVector*, unsigned long, unsigned long, Rect*) + 1105
5   com.apple.QD                    0x906ca6c9 MakeLayoutDeviceValues + 616
6   com.apple.QD                    0x906ca434 PositionDeviceGlyphs + 136
7   com.apple.QD                    0x906c87a7 TTextLineLayout::EnsureLayoutIsUpToDate(unsigned long, unsigned char, unsigned long, TATSUGlyphRecordArray**) + 501
8   com.apple.QD                    0x90747ebe TTextLineLayout::OffsetToPosition(unsigned long, unsigned char, unsigned short, ATSUCaret*, ATSUCaret*, unsigned char*) + 168
9   com.apple.QD                    0x90735ca5 ATSUOffsetToCursorPosition + 117
10  com.apple.QD                    0x90735cfc ATSUOffsetToPosition + 61
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957dea93 CUnicodeTextRun::CharacterToPixel(LineRunDisplayInfo const&, short, void*, void*) + 551
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957ef995 CLine::RunCharToPixel(LineRunInfo const*, long, unsigned char, ATSUCaret*, ATSUCaret*) + 87
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957eff7b CLine::CharacterToPixel(TCharOffset, char, ATSUCaret*) + 221
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957f0063 CLine::GetLineHilites(TCharOffsetRange, CLineHilitesList*, unsigned char, char) + 79
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957b60ea CTextensionDisplay::GetLineHilites(long, TCharOffsetRange, CLineHilitesList*, unsigned char, char) + 106
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957e8819 CSelection::CalcRangeRect(TCharOffsetRange, TLongRect*, unsigned char) + 197
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957e88df CSelection::CalcCaretRect() + 61
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957e893d CSelection::GetCaretRect(TLongRect*) + 33
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957b6132 CTextensionDisplay::CharToPoint(TCharOffset, long*, long*, long*) + 60
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957b6e66 CTextensionDisplay::CharToPoint(TCharOffset, long*) + 58
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957ebd2a CSelection::UpdateAnchors(TCharOffsetRange const&, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 98
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957b9b4b CTextensionDisplay::EndEdit(TEditInfo const&, long, long, TCharOffset*) + 165
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957c80e2 CTextension::EndEdit(TEditInfo const&, long, long, TCharOffset*, unsigned char) + 56
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957d930a CUnicodeTextension::UnicodeReplaceRange(long, long, TReplaceParams const&, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 2600
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957d9509 CUnicodeTextension::ReplaceRange(long, long, TReplaceParams const&, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 101
26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957ca5cd CReplaceTextCommand::DoMainAction() + 67
27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957ca035 CTextensionEditCommand::DoIt(short*) + 29
28  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957c9920 CTextensionCommand::Execute(short*) + 54
29  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957cf9c9 OpaqueTXNObject::ExecuteCurrCommand() + 113
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957cff11 OpaqueTXNObject::NewCommand(short, AttrObjModifier const*, TKeyDownParams*, TReplaceParams*) + 1061
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957bd030 DoSetDataCommand(OpaqueTXNObject*, unsigned long, unsigned long, TReplaceParams*) + 299
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x957c4fd3 TXNSetData + 683
33  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0171d9f8 wxMacMLTEControl::SetTXNData(wxString const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 168
34  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x017207b5 wxMacMLTEControl::WriteText(wxString const&) + 205
35  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0171fa82 wxTextCtrl::WriteText(wxString const&) + 242
36  _controls_.so                   0x05c88633 _wrap_TextCtrl_AppendText + 247 (wxPython.h:48)
37  org.python.python               0x000c8841 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20769
38  org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
39  org.python.python               0x000c8b33 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21523
40  org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
41  org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
42  org.python.python               0x00042832 function_call + 162
43  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
44  org.python.python               0x00021ff6 instancemethod_call + 422
45  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
46  org.python.python               0x000c278e PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 78
47  org.python.python               0x00038f02 PyFile_WriteObject + 354
48  org.python.python               0x000c6c4c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13612
49  org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
50  org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
51  org.python.python               0x00042832 function_call + 162
52  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
53  org.python.python               0x000c617b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10843
54  org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
55  org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
56  org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
57  org.python.python               0x00042832 function_call + 162
58  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
59  org.python.python               0x00021ff6 instancemethod_call + 422
60  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
61  org.python.python               0x0007dd17 slot_tp_init + 87
62  org.python.python               0x0007c710 type_call + 176
63  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
64  org.python.python               0x000c6ef6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14294
65  org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
66  org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
67  org.python.python               0x00042832 function_call + 162
68  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
69  org.python.python               0x00021ff6 instancemethod_call + 422
70  org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
71  org.python.python               0x000c278e PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 78
72  _core_.so                       0x0100ab2e wxPyCallback::EventThunker(wxEvent&) + 234 (helpers.cpp:1759)
73  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0169c97a wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatches(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) + 108
74  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0169ca20 wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&) + 80
75  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0169d81f wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&) + 225
76  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x016cf6b1 wxControl::ProcessCommand(wxCommandEvent&) + 27
77  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x016ca2f6 wxButton::MacControlHit(void*, void*) + 62
78  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x01734d47 wxMacWindowControlEventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 605
79  libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x017356a9 wxMacWindowEventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 197
80  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95582c2f DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1567
81  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95581ef6 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
82  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955a47f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 52
83  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f3cce SendControlHit(HIView*, OpaqueEventRef*, short, unsigned long) + 296
84  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f3b4f HIView::NotifyControlHit(OpaqueEventRef*, short, unsigned long) + 45
85  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9565865f HIView::ClickInternal(CGPoint const&, unsigned long, void (*)(OpaqueControlRef*, short), OpaqueEventRef*, bool) + 245
86  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95659c18 HIView::ClickSelf(OpaqueEventRef*) + 368
87  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95595af9 HIView::EventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 2363
88  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95582c2f DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1567
89  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95581ef6 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
90  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955a47f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 52
91  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f2b8e HIView::Click(OpaqueEventRef*) + 480
92  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f295b HandleClickAsHIView(OpaqueWindowPtr*, OpaqueEventRef*) + 151
93  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f1238 HandleWindowClick(OpaqueWindowPtr*, Point, short, unsigned long, OpaqueEventRef*) + 491
94  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f0d3b HandleMouseEvent(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*) + 786
95  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955f0652 StandardWindowEventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 93
96  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95582c2f DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1567
97  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95581ef6 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
98  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955a47f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 52
99  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955b634f ToolboxEventDispatcherHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 1257
100 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95583080 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2672
101 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95581ef6 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
102 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x955a47f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 52
103 libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x016bfd9a wxApp::MacHandleOneEvent(void*) + 34
104 libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x016bfe62 wxApp::MacDoOneEvent() + 120
105 libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x016da3de wxEventLoop::Dispatch() + 32
106 libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0179667d wxEventLoopManual::Run() + 97
107 libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib         0x0176c7fe wxAppBase::MainLoop() + 76
108 _core_.so                       0x010018dc wxPyApp::MainLoop() + 52 (helpers.cpp:215)
109 _core_.so                       0x0104f03a _wrap_PyApp_MainLoop + 82 (_core_wrap.cpp:31686)
110 org.python.python               0x000c8841 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20769
111 org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
112 org.python.python               0x00042832 function_call + 162
113 org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
114 org.python.python               0x00021ff6 instancemethod_call + 422
115 org.python.python               0x0000f5b5 PyObject_Call + 85
116 org.python.python               0x000c6ef6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14294
117 org.python.python               0x000c9933 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25107
118 org.python.python               0x000ca90a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042
119 org.python.python               0x000caa97 PyEval_EvalCode + 87
120 org.python.python               0x000ef158 PyRun_FileExFlags + 168
121 org.python.python               0x000f0087 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 855
122 org.python.python               0x00109137 Py_Main + 3255
123 org.python.python               0x00001f82 0x1000 + 3970
```

I am not sure what the problem is as it works perfectly fine on windows and unix. Any kind of help is appreciated.

EDIT : I ran this again using sudo and this time there is no crash but on the other hand there is no process started either so it made no difference. Already seen this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue9405) but how should I fix it in my case?

Comment: Have you found the fix? I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that nothing in the subprocess tries to access, create, or manipulate any UI object, including things like bitmaps or DCs.

Comment: Ya no such things there but I think its this http://bugs.python.org/issue9405 bug whose solution I cannot find.